# Where can I find a list of retrograde Milky Way stars?

Tags: orbit, orbital-mechanics, milky-way, retrograde-orbit

I read in papers that the Milky Way contains some retrograde stars (retrograde to the Milky Way rotation). Does anybody know where I can find a list of them, possibly including data on their distance from the Milky way center?
many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Milky Way's outer halo has many globular clusters with a retrograde orbit (about 40% of all clusters in Milky Way). One of the more prominent example include [Kapteyn's star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapteyn%27s_Star) which is highly retrograde due to it being ripped from a dwarf galaxy and merging with the Milky Way.

However, the structure of the halo is a topic of an ongoing debate. Several studies have claimed that the halo consists of two distinct components. The "inner" halo consists of more metal-rich, prograde stars and "outer" halo consisting of metal-poor, retrograde stars. These findings have been challenged many times due to the argument on the topic of "duality of motion".

More readings here:

1. [Carollo et al. 2007](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2007Natur.450.1020C/abstract)
2. [Kravtsov 2001](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001A%26AT...20.1066K/abstract)
3. [Kordopatis et al. 2020](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2020A%26A...643A..69K/abstract)

Comment: very interesting thanks. Can I ask what you mean with duality of motion?

Comment: also, is it at least true that the inner part contains prograde objects and the outer part retrograde? Or are they mixed? many thanks

Comment: @magnolia1 duality of motion means some object moving/rotation in one direction and others in opposite directions simultaneously within a same reference frame. Some studies have noted the separation of halo into two _distinct_ components where the clusters show contrasting behaviour but it hasn't been proved yet. So, it is a subject of ongoing debate.